# Alternative definition of $\chi_{k}(x)$

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Assume $q:B\rightarrow I$ is a local homeomorphism, and $A\subseteq B$ is open. Consider arbitrary $x\in B$, and $S$ is an open nbhd of $x$ such that $q\upharpoonright S$ is homeomorphism (locally).

Define $U_x=\{i\in I|\text{there exists some local section $s$ of $(B,q)$ such that $s(i)\in A$ and $s(q(x))=x$}\}$.

Then it is not hard to show that $U_x$ is open in $I$.

$\textbf{Now the question is}$ : prove $[U_x]_{q(x)}=[q(A\cap X)]_{q(x)}$, i.e. there exists an open nbhd $V$ of $q(x)$ such that $U_x\cap V=q(A\cap S)\cap V$.

It is an exercise in Topoi: The Categorial Analysis of Logic by Robert Goldblatt : Exercise 2 on page 100. I tried $V=q(S)$, but then realized that some strange local section might makes some $i\in q(S)-q(A\cap S)$ in $U_x$.